# Creating constructor for an Auction that makes an object containing an ArrayList of previously unsold Lots

Tags: java, constructor, bluej

Not sure if my title is worded okay, but
I'm using BlueJ to learn a bit of Java, and I'm working on an Auction project (based off an example in chapter 4 of *Objects First With Java: A Practical Introduction Using BlueJ*, with some changes). What I'm trying to do is add a second constructor that takes an Auction as parameter, and if that Auction is currently closed, creates a new Auction with the unsold lots from it. If it it's still open or null, this constructor should work like my default constructor.

Here's the start of my code with my default constructor:

```
...

public class Auction
{
    // The list of Lots in this auction.
    private ArrayList<Lot> lots;
    // The number that will be given to the next lot entered
    // into this auction.
    private int nextLotNumber;
    // Whether or not the auction is open for bidding.
    private boolean openForBid;

    /**
     * Create a new auction.
     */
    public Auction()
    {
        lots = new ArrayList<Lot>();
        nextLotNumber = 1;
        openForBid = true;
    }

    /**
     * Second Constructor
     */ 
    public Auction(Auction auction)
    {
        //If the auction is open..
            //Create a new Auction the same as above
        //else..
            //create a new auction with unsold lots from the specified auction
    }
```

I am working off of a skeleton for this Auction class with little instruction, but there is a method that should return an ArrayList of the lots which currently have no bids.

```
public ArrayList<Lot> getNoBids()
```

So I figure I need to call that on the Auction passed to the constructor, but I can't seem to wrap my head around putting this all together. Any help is appreciated as I am fairly new to Java and ArrayLists! Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear on the question; why can't you call that method on the auction passed to the constructor?

Comment: @DaveNewton I know I'll be able to call it, I'm just having trouble designing the constructor itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the the default behavior/constructor set to open you could have the following:

```
public Auction(Auction auction) {

   this();

   if (!auction.openClosed) {
      lots.addAll(auction.getNoBids());
      // set close flags as necessary...
   }
}
```

Also using a variable like `openClosed` is confusing. It could be called `openForBidding` which would make its purpose clearer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, and I went ahead and renamed that variable as it does seem pretty confusing!

Answer (score 1):

If given the passed `Auction auction` status(as closed), you want to add lots to new Auction, you can do as below:

```
public Auction(Auction auction)  {
     this.lots =new ArrayList<Lot>();
     openClosed = true;
     if(!auction.isOpenForBid()){
       nextLotNumber = 1;
       this.lots.addAll(auction.getLots()); 
    }else{
       nextLotNumber = this.lots.size(); 
    }
}
```

I imagine, in both the conditions, `openClosed` should be set to true, and if you are adding lots from previous auction, you may want to initialize `nextLotNumber` accordingly i.e. with the lot size being added.

Comment: thanks for the tip about initializing nextLotNumber after the lots are added. The only thing regarding your code is that I'd rather not create a new isOpenForBid method, and this would add all lots from the parameter auction and not just the unsold ones wouldn't it?

Comment: You have already accepted one answer so I hope your problem is resolved, which does the same thing (adds all lots). Still if you question around adding open lots, please let me know. Regarding `isOpenForBid()`, I prefer accessing attributes through accessor method if they don't belong to same Object instance.

Answer (score -1):

This credit should go to Reimeus above, but I can't seem to comment on his answer.

Basically, he was right, except for the need to call this() instead of super().

```
  public Auction(Auction auction)
  {
      this();

      if (!auction.openClosed) {
         lots.addAll(auction.getNoBids());
         // set close flags as necessary...
      }
  }
```

Comment: Looks very like my answer :))

Comment: Including the comment and inconsistent brace placement. Hmm.

Comment: @Reimeus, Ugh, sorry about that, I didn't see that you had already answered it. I need to be faster at answering :)

Comment: Wow, I just realized I referenced the wrong name too.. i'm slacking tonight!

Comment: For a trivial error, a comment or proposed edit is generally better than a duplicate answer, IMO.